# For looping through JSONArray causes crash

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the JSONStrings from https://github.com/thiagobodruk/bible/blob/master/json/en_kjv.json and show them to a ListView but the problem is, the CPU cannot handle the process and crashes the app.

The `en_kjv.json` is in AWS S3 and I'm getting the content using Volley.

Volley Code:

```java
StringRequest requestKJV = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                processDone(response, "Genesis");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something wen't wrong whilst loading KJV. Please make sure your WiFi/Cellular Data was connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ArrayList<String> listER = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterER = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview, R.id.items);
            }
        });
```

`processDone();` code:

```java
public void processDone(String mainStringJson, String name) {
        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterLP = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.listview, R.id.line, list);
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[" + mainStringJson + "]");
            for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(jsonObject.getString("name").equals(name)) {
                    JSONArray chapterArrays = jsonObject.getJSONArray("chapters");
                    for(int iA=0; iA < chapterArrays.length(); iA++) {
                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = chapterArrays.getJSONArray(iA);
                        for(int iB=0; iB < jsonArray1.length(); iB++) {
                            arrayAdapterLP.add(jsonArray1.getString(iB));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException jsonE){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something wen't wrong. " + jsonE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapterLP);
    }
```

In Logcat I get `Task was cancelled` and sometimes `Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get the JSONStrings from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thiagobodruk/bible/master/json/en_kjv.json

And you should use **Retrofit2**, **OkHttp** instead of **StringRequest**

Comment: No, but I downloaded the file from GitHub and uploaded to AWS s3 and ok.